# An unknown connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher ..... The SSL connection request has failed

Tags: ssl, certificate, .net, development, schannel

I am getting too frequent errors in my System Error Logs :

> An unknown connection request was received from a remote client
>   application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client
>   application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request
>   has failed.

In one of our .net web application. We are also getting a certificate related issue. May be these two issues are inter-related. The error we see in application logs is :

```
Merchnant Update Service returned  Exception[System.InvalidOperationException: General Error https://www.mytestwebsite.pk/appli/index/WSDL?wsdl?wsdl ---> System.Net.WebException: There was an error downloading 'https://www.mytestwebsite.pk/appli/index/WSDL?wsdl?wsdl'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Download(String& url, String& contentType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Download(String& url, String& contentType)
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.DiscoverAny(String url)
   at DynamicWebServiceInvoker.Wsdl.ProcessRemoteUrls(DiscoveryClientProtocol client, StringCollection urls, XmlSchemas schemas, ServiceDescriptionCollection descriptions) in E:\Apps\DynamicWebServiceInvoker\Wsdl.cs:line 699
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DynamicWebServiceInvoker.Manager.Generate(String url) in E:\Apps\DynamicWebServiceInvoker\Manager.cs:line 47
   at ExternalStatusService.Caller.UpdateMerchant(UpdateStatusServiceDTO ServiceInfo)] <EOL>
```

[Event Log Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObaUV.png)

Comment: That can be anything, specifically it can be some client just probing your site (for example like SSLLabs). Unless you can match these log entries with customer issues you can probably simple ignore these. As for your certificate problems - you provide zero details about these so it is impossible to tell what the problem is and if it is related to the other one.

Comment: @Steffen : Regarding the certificate issue, When we call the URL (https://www.mytestwebsite.pk/appli/index/WSDL?wsdl?wsdl) from a chrome browser from our web server, it opens fine and shows the WSDL but as soon as we call this URL from our application code it throws above exception shown in the question. As per the URL server, they are using TLS 1.5 , also our server as a client in this call has TLS 1.5 enabled in registery for Server.

Comment: There is no TLS 1.5. Please check your information again. Also, make sure that your server and client have some overlap in the supported TLS protocol versions and ciphers.

Comment: That was a typo. Correct one is TLS 1.2